# Is there a way to make intellij debugger not step into every recursive call?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug recursive functions and it automatically steps into every recursive call. Why would it ever do that when it has a step into button and it doesn't do that with other function calls? I know you can see the call stack and manually revert back, but that is very time consuming and easy to mess up. Is there a way to make it just not decide to automatically step into recursive calls that I haven't told it to step into?

Comment: do you mean the "Step Over (F8)" function? Or more like the "Do not step into the classes" settings?

Comment: I guess you have a breakpoint in your function, and the debugger stops there every time this code is executed, which means in every recursive call, even if you select the "Step Over" option. If you want to control when to go into a call, disable/remove the breakpoint and use the "Step Into" and "Step Over" options.